# shutdown: Unable to shutdown system from root shell (init=/bin/bash). (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, root

I made some changes in the boot options in grub to directly login into the root shell viz.

1. Press <kbd>e</kbd> at the GRUB2 boot menu.
2. Change the line `ro quite splash $vt_handoff` with `rw init=/bin/bash`
3. press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

following above steps I was able to login into root shell successfully and changed the password of root.

now when I am issuing `reboot` or `poweroff` command, I am getting below error:

```
shutdown: unable to shutdown system
```

If I am trying to run `startx` to go into the GUI the system is hanging every time.

Any resolutions??

PS: I didn't face any other issue before on this system in last 3 months since I upgraded to 14.04.

Comment: Try holding SYSRQ button, and then press one by one r,e,i,s,u,o. Usually this sequence would be r,e,i,s,u,b, where b stands for reboot, but o stands for shutdown (since that's what you've requested). LEt me know if this helps, and i will post this as official answer

Answer (score 7):

First you must activate the magic SysRq option:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

When you are ready to reboot the machine simply run the following:

```
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

[Source](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/rebooting-magic-way).

Comment: apt-get install systemd-sysv

Comment: Note that this ["Will immediately reboot the system without syncing or unmounting your disks."](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/sysrq.html#what-are-the-command-keys), i.e. not a proper equivalent to a `reboot` or `shutdown`.

Answer (score 4):

> Any resolutions??

Yes.  Don't do that.  Don't expect `init=/bin/{bash,sh}` to give a functional system that you can just use as normal.  It doesn't.  *You* have the burden of *doing everything by hand* that normally a proper system manager program would be doing for you.

Don't expect `shutdown`, and indeed quite a few other system utilities, to work in the case where you are running a shell as process #1.  A shell doesn't do the necessary basic system management tasks required of process #1, and it doesn't speak the necessary protocols expected by commands such as `shutdown`.  In this particular case, the upstart `shutdown` program (which is what it is) is trying to open a Desktop Bus connection to upstart, in order to tell upstart to shut down the system; but since you never ran upstart in the first place there's no system manager for `shutdown` to talk to.

*You* have the burden of *doing everything by hand* that a system manager would normally do for you in order to shut down the system, including flushing the filesystem cache, unmounting filesystems cleanly, and then enacting the raw final poweroff/halt/reboot action.

For the same reason, don't expect complex "desktop environments" — that depend from things like *session inits*; running Desktop Bus and "kit" servers; and basic system initialization steps like having all of the filesystems (including the "API" ones) properly mounted, all of the necessary loadable kernel modules loaded, and all of the sysctl/whatever settings set — to work in the case where *you just ran a shell and didn't do any of the stuff that a system manager program and system initialization have to do*.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197472/5132

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It does answer a question, one that the user asking the original question already knew the answer to. Why did you write this??